# displaying slider value

Tags: jquery, uislider

i am using *jquery slider* . Is there any default function to **display slider value** under slider object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no  'default function' to display slider value under slider object.

Comment: But can use the slide function to perform this one.

Answer (score 3):

Get or set the value option, after init.  From [option-value](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider#option-value)

```
var value = $('.selector').slider('option', 'value');
```

> Determines the value of the slider, if
>   there's only one handle. If there is
>   more than one handle, determines the
>   value of the first handle.

***Edit:***

Use the slide event for displaying the value when the slider is changed

[slide](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider#event-slide)

This event is triggered on every mouse move during slide. Use ui.value (single-handled sliders) to obtain the value of the current handle, $(..).slider('value', index) to get another handles' value.

Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the slide event as an init option.

```
$('.selector').slider({
   slide: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Bind to the slide event by type: slide.

```
$('.selector').bind('slide', function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: i need a solution to display the value not to set the value

Comment: This one gets the value in the variable 'value'.

Comment: ya you are right but i'm asking any default function along with slider. To set manually we have to take care of the alignment using css